# Como verificar a eficiência dessas 2 funções em C++?

Tags: c++, loop, desempenho, recursão, teoria-da-computação

Como determinar qual é a melhor escolha dentre estas duas funções para implementação?

1:

```
int X(int x){

if(x<=0)
    return 0;

return(x + X(x-1));
}
```

2:

```
int Y(int x){

int soma=0;

for(int i=0;i<=x;++i)
    soma+=i;

return soma;
}
```

Como determinar as equações de complexidade e resolvê-las? Ou há outro método?

Comment: A segunda é mais agradável.

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer dizer com "equações de complexidade" ? Você que saber qual a forma mais eficiente ?

Answer (score 10):

No geral, as respostas até o momento tratam a mensuração da eficiência em termos práticos.

Vou dar uma resposta em termos teóricos, já que você faz duas perguntas: Como determinar as equações de complexidade e se há outro método.

Para responder a primeira pergunta, em primeiro lugar recomendo um livro introdutório de algoritmos que ensine notação Big-O.

Os livros que recomendo são:

- [Algoritmos: Teoria e Prática](http://www.submarino.com.br/produto/111052655/algoritmos-teoria-e-pratica?DCSext.recom=Neemu_Produto_viu-comprou-2&nm_origem=rec_produto_viu-comprou-2&nm_ranking_rec=1) - Conhecido internacionalmente, particularmente só tive acesso à [versão em inglês](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844).
- [Algorithms Unlocked](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262518805) - Não tive acesso, mas é bem recomendado por ser uma versão menos longa do livro anterior. Escrito pelo mesmo autor renomado.
- [Schaum's Outline of Discrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071615865) - Gosto deste livro por ser bem direto, mais apropriado pra quem não é iniciante talvez. Não exatamente focado em algoritmos, abrange várias áreas importantes das ciências da computação (particularmente sinto ser até mais acessível que "Algoritmos: Teoria e Prática" em certos pontos no tocante a algoritmos).

Vou reduzir a análise em miúdos, de forma não rigorosa, sem envolver *loop invariants*, etc.

Primeiro o mais fácil de analisar, o caso 2.

Este caso consiste em apenas um loop que repete uma operação de complexidade O(1). A quantidade de repetições é diretamente proporcional ao valor de entrada da função. Se o argumento `x` for `N`, então o loop será repetido `N` vezes. Fora o loop, o corpo da função só tem outras operações de complexidade O(1):

```
int Y(int x) { // O(1)
    int soma=0; // O(1)

          // O(1)   O(1)   O(1)
    for(  int i=0;  i<=x;  ++i  )
        soma+=i; // O(1)
    // O() do loop = O(x) == O(1) + x*O(1) + x*O(1) + x*O(1)

    return soma; // O(1)
}
// O() da função = O(x) == O(1) + O(1) + O(x) + O(1)
```

Portanto esta função tem complexidade O(N) no tempo. Nota-se que esta função realiza seu cálculo com uma quantidade fixa de variáveis locais somente, portanto ela é O(1) no espaço usado (ou seja, não precisa de mais memória dependendo da entrada).

O primeiro caso é uma função recursiva, e a análise de complexidade se torna recursiva também. Existe uma teoria sólida para isto, mas irei me ater a uma
explicação simplória.

Note que, todas as operações no corpo da função, exceto a própria chamada recursiva, são O(1). As chamadas recursivas ocorrerão até que se chegue a condição de término. Nota-se que para uma entrada `x = N`, ocorreram `N` chamadas. Dado que em cada chamada, fora a chamada recursiva, são realizadas operações O(1), então a complexidade no tempo desta função também é O(N).

A complexidade no espaço desta função difere do caso 2. Pelo fato de ser uma função recursiva cujo resultado precisa ser agregado como uma soma no final, ela não é uma função *[tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)*, e portanto não é possível que o compilador otimize sua função utilizando esta técnica.

Dado que *tail-recursion* não é possível, a cada chamada recursiva é preciso que se empilhe na pilha de chamada um número fixo de dados (argumentos da função, endereço de retorno, etc). Ou seja, para `N` chamadas, ocorreram `N`empilhamentos de dados de um tamanho determinado, portanto a função é O(N) no espaço que utiliza também.

Respondendo à segunda pergunta: Há outro método?

Você tem duas soluções para o problema, uma é O(N) no tempo e O(N) no espaço, uma é O(N) no tempo e O(1) no espaço.

Uma alternativa seria procurar uma solução cuja complexidade não dependa do valor de entrada, será que é possível uma solução O(1) no tempo e O(1) no espaço?

Note que:

- y = 1 + 2 + 3 ... + (x - 2) + (x - 1) + x
- y - x * x = (1 - x) + (2 - x) + (3 - x) ... + [(x - 2) - x] + [(x - 1) - x] + (x - x)
- -(y - x * x) = (x - 1) + (x - 2) + (x - 3) ... + 2 + 1 + 0
- x * x - y = 1 + 2... + (x - 3) + (x - 2) + (x - 1)
- x * x - y = y - x
- x * x + x = 2y
- y = x * (x + 1) / 2

Desta formula (uma dedução básica da soma dos elementos de uma progressão aritmética), é possível obter o valor da soma a partir do valor de entrada com complexidade O(1), ou seja, sem loops.

Então o método mais eficiente seria:

```
int Z(int x) { // O(1)
    return (x * (x + 1)) / 2; // O(1)
}
```

(Se você já se perguntou na vida onde que iria usar PA e PG ensinado na escola, tá aí ;-) )

Se você quisesse ser mais eficiente ainda, com C++11 poderia declarar a função como
`constexpr`.

```
constexpr int Z(int x) {
    return (x * (x + 1)) / 2;
}
```

Assim, a maioria dos compiladores que suporta C++11 faria o cálculo da soma em tempo de compilação, incorrendo em nenhum cálculo em tempo de execução, **quando o argumento passado for uma constante**. Caso o argumento não seja uma constante (i.e. um valor de tempo de execução), a função obtém a mesma eficiência de uma versão `inline`.

Comment: Muito show! + 1

Comment: Resposta fantástica! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Melhorando o desempenho:**

No g++ existe a flag `-Ofast` que faz várias modificações durante a fase de compilação do seu algoritmo e, na maioria das vezes, ele fica muito mais eficiente!

Já reduzi execuções que duravam 20 minutos para menos de 1!

**Segue um exemplo:**

> g++ main.cpp -o App.exe -Ofast

Faça o teste, calcule o tempo de execução conforme as outras respostas sugerem e tire suas próprias conclusões!

Answer (score 4):

No Windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() { 
    int i, j; 
    int inicio, final, tmili; 

    inicio = GetTickCount(); 

    /* Substitua o for a seguir pelo trecho de código 
       cujo tempo de execução deverá ser medido. */

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j ++) 
        for (i = 0; i < 1387634340; i ++); 
    final = GetTickCount();
    tmili = final - inicio; 

    printf("tempo decorrido: %d\n", tmili); 
    return 0; 
}}
```

No Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() { 
    int i, j;
    struct timeval inicio, final;
    int tmili;

    gettimeofday(&inicio, NULL);

    /* Substitua o for a seguir pelo trecho de código 
       cujo tempo de execução deverá ser medido. */

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j ++) 
        for (i = 0; i < 1387634340; i ++); 
    gettimeofday(&final, NULL);
    tmili = (int) (1000 * (final.tv_sec - inicio.tv_sec) + (final.tv_usec - inicio.tv_usec) / 1000);

    printf("tempo decorrido: %d\n", tmili); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Como calcular a eficiência eu não sei mas posso testá-la:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdint>

#ifdef WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ctime>
#endif

/* Returns the amount of milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch. Works on both
 * windows and linux. */

uint64_t get_time()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
 /* Windows */
 FILETIME ft;
 LARGE_INTEGER li;

 /* Get the amount of 100 nano seconds intervals elapsed since January 1, 1601 (UTC) and copy it
  * to a LARGE_INTEGER structure. */
 GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
 li.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
 li.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;

 uint64_t ret = li.QuadPart;
 ret -= 116444736000000000LL; /* Convert from file time to UNIX epoch time. */
 ret /= 10000; /* From 100 nano seconds (10^-7) to 1 millisecond (10^-3) intervals */

 return ret;
#else
 /* Linux */
 struct timeval tv;

 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

 uint64_t ret = tv.tv_usec;
 /* Convert from micro seconds (10^-6) to milliseconds (10^-3) */
 ret /= 1000;

 /* Adds the seconds (10^0) after converting them to milliseconds (10^-3) */
 ret += (tv.tv_sec * 1000);

 return ret;
#endif
}

int X(int x){
    if(x<=0)
        return 0;
    return(x + X(x-1));
}

int Y(int x){
    int soma=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=x;++i)
        soma+=i;
    return soma;
}

int main(void) {
    uint64_t startTime, endTime, timeElapsed;
    startTime = get_time();
    X(300000);
    endTime = get_time();
    timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
    printf("Tempo decorrido: %d\n", timeElapsed);
    startTime = get_time();
    Y(300000);
    endTime = get_time();
    timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
    printf("Tempo decorrido: %d\n", timeElapsed);

    return 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Library/BenchmarkPerformance.cpp).

Fiz um teste e a segunda foi claramente muito mais eficiente, pelo menos 7 vezes mais rápida. Não consegui postar em nenhum site *online* que permitisse executar corretamente. Onde executou não dá para compartilhar.

A função de medição foi retirada dessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1861337/221800).

Comment: "[...] a segunda foi claramente muito mais eficiente [...]" - e a explicação teórica do porquê disso está muito bem dada na resposta do @pepper_chico. :)